# jQuery: Button add and remove closest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML as follows:

```
<div class="parent-wrapper">
    <div class="test-guided-search-row">
        <select class="form-control test-guided-search-row-select-bool-query">
            <option>AND</option>
        </select>

        <select class="form-control test-guided-search-row-select-query-path">
            <option>ALL</option>
        </select>

        <select class="form-control test-guided-search-row-query-type">
            <option>abcd</option>
            <option>efg</option>
        </select>

        <input class="form-control" type="text">

        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" data-button-action="addRow">+</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="button" data-button-action="deleteRow">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that the button + will add the entire row `div` next to the div in which the button that was clicked? I am having trouble with this because there are multiple of these row divs and I want to be able to add row next to this div row and remove only that row.

Comment: can you also add desired html once + is clicked?

Comment: So you're trying to make the `+` button clone the current row and append it, and the `-` button remove the row that was clicked, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need to use delegated event handlers as the `button` elements will be dynamically appended to the DOM. From there you can use `closest()` to find the row, along with `clone()` and `append()` or `remove()` respectively.

Firstly, add classes to the buttons to make identifying them easier:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-add" type="button" data-button-action="addRow">+</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-delete" type="button" data-button-action="deleteRow">-</button>
```

Then you can attach events to them:

```
$('.parent-wrapper').on('click', '.btn-add', function() {
    $(this).closest('.test-guided-search-row').clone().appendTo('.parent-wrapper');
}).on('click', '.btn-delete', function() {
    $(this).closest('.test-guided-search-row').remove();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/757msav7/)

Answer (score 1):

find your row, clone it, append it.

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('.test-guided-search-row').clone();
    $('.parent-wrapper').append(row);
})
```

find your row, delete it. 
delete

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('.test-guided-search-row').remove();
})
```

// you need to define what button is + what button is - with a class name

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.parent-wrapper').on('click', '.btn-add', function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('.test-guided-search-row').clone();
    $(this).closest('.test-guided-search-row').after(row);
}).on('click', '.btn-delete', function() {
    $(this).closest('.test-guided-search-row').remove();
});
```

This is what exactly solved my issue. I wanted to append to the closest button click row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to add row next to a particular div row and remove only that row, you need to add a number as the id to each

This might help:
Pass

```
$(this).closest('.new-wrapper')[0].id
```

to addRow(rowId) when clicking on the + button.

```
function addRow(rowId){
  var next = rowId+1;
  $(".parent-wrapper #rowId").after('<div id="'+next+'" class = "new-wrapper"> $(".test-guided-search-row").html() </div>);
}
```